# How can I get the selected data/item rows in CheckboxColumn Gridview - Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

**I have a problem on getting all the selected values/data Yii2 Gridview using checkboxColumn.**

I can only get **one** of the **value** in the **grid** using this code:

```
         'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
         'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            return ['value' => $model['item_id'] ];
         },
```

Need some suggestions on how can I get all the values in the grid...

**Here is my Code Code snippet Controller/View:**

**Controller:**

```
public function actionBulk(){
   $action=Yii::$app->request->post('action');
   $selection=(array)Yii::$app->request->post('selection');
   print_r($selection);
}
```

**View:**

```
<?=Html::beginForm(['transjournal/bulk'],'post');?>

<?=GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'bordered'=>true,
    'striped'=>true,
    'condensed'=>true,
    'hover'=>true,
    'export' => false,
    'showOnEmpty' => false,
    'panel'=>[
            'after'=>Html::submitButton('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Posted', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']),
    ],
    'columns' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
        'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            return ['value' => $model['item_id'] ];
         },
    ],
        'item_id',
        'description',
    ],
  ]);
?>

<?= Html::endForm();?>
```

**Here is my attachment:**

[This is the GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v12Gr.jpg)

[image]

[This is the Result in the GridView (Selected Data only returns item_id)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhkv1.jpg)

[image]

**How can I return both item_id and description?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue  with your code `'checkboxOptions' =>`, can you remove it?

```
<?=Html::beginForm(['controller/bulk'],'post');?>

<?=Html::dropDownList('action','',[''=>'Mark selected as: ','c'=>'Confirmed','nc'=>'No Confirmed'],['class'=>'dropdown',])?>

<?=Html::submitButton('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-info',]);?>

<?=GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
       ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        ...
     ],
  ]); ?>

<?= Html::endForm();?>
```

In Controller:

```
 public function actionBulk(){
       $action=Yii::$app->request->post('action');
       $selection=(array)Yii::$app->request->post('selection');//typecasting
       foreach($selection as $id){
        $model = Post::findOne((int)$id);//make a typecasting
        //do your stuff
        $model->save();
        // or delete
      }
    }
```

Comment: tnx @muhammad-shahzad

Answer (score 1):

basically, i am using yii's CheckboxColumn:

```
<?php
    namespace common\grid;

    class CheckboxColumn extends \yii\grid\CheckboxColumn {

        public $headerOptions  = ['class' => 'text-center', 'style' => 'width: 5em'];
        public $contentOptions = ['class' => 'text-center'];

    }
?>
```

then i wrote a jquery plugin for triggering operations with selected items, plus custom Actions and so on, here the relevant javascript code, where `options.grid` is the id/selector for your grid, e.g. `'#grid'`:

```
    var selection = [];
    $(options.grid + ' input:checkbox[name="selection[]"]:checked').each(function() {
        selection.push($(this).val());
    });
```

so `var selection` contains an array with my item ids. length is:

```
selection.length
```

Comment: tnx for the reply . but I guess I'm going to query the selected ID from the grid...

Comment: you can pass the gridview's id as a parameter. then use this #id instead "options.grid"