# Retrieving data from Gridview as array in Yii2

Tags: yii2

i'd like to ask how to retrieving data as array from gridview
as mentioned in this thread 
[How can I get the selected data/item rows in CheckboxColumn Gridview - Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893566/how-can-i-get-the-selected-data-item-rows-in-checkboxcolumn-gridview-yii2)

what i have been doing is :
in the controller

```
public function actionCetakdispo{

$action=Yii::$app->request->post('action');
$selection=(array)Yii::$app->request->post('selection');
print_r($selection);
exit;
}
```

in view :

```
    <?=Html::beginForm(['controller/rekapsm'],'post');?>
    <?= Html::a('Cetak Dispo', ['cetakdispo'], ['class' => 'btn btn- 
    primary']) ?>
    <?= Html::a('Cetak Register', ['cetakreg'], ['class' => 'btn btn- 
    primary']) ?>    

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,

    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'kategori',
        'nama_wp',
        'nama',             
        'nomor_surat', 
        'tgl_surat',
        'perihal',
        'ket',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

but nothing data retrieve to array..please give me lessons or referrence to read..many thanks..

UPDATED :
i change view become likethis :

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:870px;" >

    <?=Html::beginForm(['cetakdispo'],'post');?>
    <?=Html::submitButton('Cetak Dispo', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);?>
    <?= Html::a('Cetak Register', ['cetakreg'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

</div>

<?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,

    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',],
        'id',
        'kategori',
        'nama_wp',
        'nama',             
        'nomor_surat', 
        'tgl_surat',
        'perihal',
        'ket',
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            return ['value' => $model['id'] ];
         },],
    ],
]); ?>



<?= Html::endForm();?> 
</div>
```

and its works...

Comment: you are using `controller/rekapsm` where as you should provide the actual controller name and the action name for the form's `action` attribute,you never told what is happening when you click the submnit button after selecting the check boxes. Also your form has no `Html::endForm()` .

Comment: if i change into this  Html::a(['rekapsm/cetakdispo'],'post'); its show error Array to string conversion

Comment: i was talking about the `Html::beginForm(['controller/rekapsm'],'post');` not the anchor please read the documentation on [HELPER HTML](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-html#forms)

Comment: very well mr omar .. thx